# If I download something something from the Xbox Games Store on X360 will it have the same game saves as disc version?

Tags: xbox-360

If I download a game from the Xbox Games Store on Xbox 360 will it have the same game files and saves from the disc version? Specific game in mind is Sonic Unleashed.

Comment: I'm almost certain this works. I started writing an answer but I'm having trouble thinking of a specific example where I definitely did this.

Comment: @DCShannon for me, this worked with Skyrim, Darks Souls 1, Darksiders, as well as a few Arcade games